# slanted sukka roof frame

Tags: halacha, sukkah, architecture-design

Would a sukkah frame design with a slant on the roof, e.g. following the diagram [on this page](https://creativeshelters.com/designapp/slant/standard), be kosher?

Comment: G. Fried, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here!  As you can see, we have an existing post covering your question, so your post is helpful for providing more avenues for Internet searchers to find this content. If this question affects you practically, I recommend [getting advice from your own rabbi](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) before putting into practice any ideas found here.